# Storing a view in Xamarin.Forms MvvmCross

Tags: xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

I have an app with four main pages, switched through a tab bar (no "back" button).
One page has a lot of content (ScrollView) and takes quite a few seconds until it's rendered. I handle that by showing a "loading" overlay while the work is done. But for that specific page I'd like to keep the view alive, so that when the user switches to another page and comes back later, the page is ready without loading everything again.
I'm not sure how to do that in MvvmCross, though.

I did read the documentation and from what I understood the [View Presenter](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/view-presenters) would be the right way to do it, since the docs say:

> "Another kind of presentation changes your app can request through
> hints includes clearing / modifying the BackStack, changing a root
> while maintaining the existent views, … possibilities are really
> endless. Once again your app is king here!"

I guess I would need to create a custom MvxPresentationHint for that, but I don't quite get it :(
How or rather where would I access and store/load the View?

I'm generally still quite unfamiliar with MvvmCross (how it works under the hood) and especially customization of Mvx classes, even though I've been using it for a while.
Any explanation and preferably code examples beyond what's written in the documentation would be extremely appreciated!

Comment: The point of any MVVM library, is that you represent the state of the view as a “view model” (VM). That is a class you define, that has properties for all the changing details of your view. So it is the VM you need to save, not the view. To restore, you need to load that VM (from wherever you saved it). Then you set the view’s BindingContext to that VM, and the view is re-created as it was. Google c# mvvm restoring ui state from view model.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @ToolmakerSteve :)
I already do store the VM to keep the state, but it's the drawing of the elements that takes so long, not the construction of the VM itself. Storing the VM didn't help much in that regard, as the view is still recreated on navigation.
What I'd need is that the view never actually closes, kinda like when you use the "back" button (pulled from the stack I think), but doing that same thing whenever clicking the tab.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't meaningful to attempt to "store" a view in MVVM. The XF view is a representation of what will be created with native (e.g. "Android" or "iOS") widgets. Creating and measuring/laying out those native widgets is what is slow. MVVM View Presenter won't speed up that logic.

Instead of "store", you need "keep alive":

For a `ContentPage` called `MyPage`, when you create it, **store it in a static variable.** Then re-use that variable. If you never need more than one of these, you can store it in the class itself.

Modify the "code behind", `MyPage.xaml.cs`:

```
public partial class MyPage : ContentPage
{
    // Singleton Pattern.
    private static MyPage _it;
    public static MyPage It {
        get {
            if (_it == null)
                _it = new MyPage();
            return _it;
        }
    }

    // "private", because calling this directly defeats the purpose. Instead, use `MyPage.It`.
    private MyPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

To create it, whereever you would put:

```
new MyPage()
```

instead put this:

```
MyPage.It
```

For instance, you might do `PushAsync(MyPage.It);`

This will always return the SAME INSTANCE of MyPage. So once it has been created, it keeps its state.

IMPORTANT: Note that the constructor is only called ONCE. Any code that needs to be done each time the page appears, put in `override .. OnAppearing()` method.

LIMITATION: Views "expect" to be part of the visual hierarchy when they are manipulated. **If you attempt to alter the page or its view model while it is not on the screen,** you may encounter problems. Those are beyond the scope of this answer - create a new StackOverflow question with the details of any problem you encounter.

Comment: thank you very much for the answer! I will try it :)

Comment: Hi @ToolmakerSteve,
The static view alone didn't work for me, unfortunately.
But I managed to keep it alive by opening other pages as modals and then simply closing it, so it works similar to the back navigation when activated.

BUT I do have the problem, that the bindings are lost. RaiseProperty() doesn't work anymore once the view has disappeared and reappeared. Do you have any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: This also happens with the "WrapInNavigationPage" attribute, btw.

Comment: @Laila - best to make a new question about the lost bindings. You’ll need to show all the code that is involved, for someone to figure that out. I haven’t used MvvmCross, so not sure.